# Unable to crawl multiple pages

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl quotes, author names and tags from [goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes). I am able to crawl single page with following code

```
import scrapy 


class goodReadsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
#identity
name='goodreads'

#requests
def start_requests(self):
    url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?page=1'
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse)


#reponse
def parse(self,response):
   for quote in response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
    yield{
        'text':quote.xpath('.//div[@class = "quoteText"]/text()[1]').extract(),
        'author':quote.xpath('.//span[@class = "authorOrTitle"]').extract_first(),
        'tags':quote.xpath('.//div[@class="greyText smallText left"]/a/text()').extract()
    }
```

but when I try to crawl same spider with addition of following code

```
 next_page = response.selector.xpath('//a[@class = "next_page"/@href').extract()



 if next_page is not None:
           next_page_link = response.urljoin(next_page)
           yield scrapy.request(url=next_page_link, callback=self.parse)
```

I get the following error.

> 2019-05-29 10:47:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
>   2019-05-29 10:47:14 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages
>   (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)   2019-05-29
>   10:47:14 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on
>   127.0.0.1:6023   2019-05-29 10:47:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.goodreads.com/robots.txt> (referer:
>   None)   2019-05-29 10:47:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200)
>   https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?page=1> (referer: None)
>   2019-05-29 10:47:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200
>   https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?page=1>   {'text': ["\n      “Don't
>   cry because it's over, smile because it happened.”\n  "], 'author':
>   '\n    Dr. Seuss\n  ', 'tags':
>   ['attributed-no-source', 'cry', 'crying', 'experience', 'happiness',
>   'joy', 'life', 'misattributed-dr-seuss', 'optimism', 'sadness',
>   'smile', 'smiling']}   2019-05-29 10:47:16 [scrapy.core.scraper]
>   ERROR: Spider error processing https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?page=1> (referer: None)   Traceback
>   (most recent call last):     File
>   "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line
>   238, in xpath
>       **kwargs)     File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1586, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath     File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 307, in
>   lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.**call**     File
>   "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 227, in
>   lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
>   lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid predicate
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):     File
>   "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py",
>   line 102, in iter_errback
>       yield next(it)     File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py",
>   line 29, in process_spider_output
>       for x in result:     File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py",
>   line 339, in 
>       return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())     File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py",
>   line 37, in 
>       return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))     File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))     File "C:\Users\Zona\Documents\Visual\demo_project\demo_project\spiders\goodreads.py",
>   line 23, in parse
>       next_page = response.selector.xpath('//a[@class = "next_page"/@href').extract()     File
>   "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line
>   242, in xpath
>       six.reraise(ValueError, ValueError(msg), sys.exc_info()[2])     File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 692, in
>   reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb)     File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line
>   238, in xpath
>       **kwargs)     File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1586, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath     File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 307, in
>   lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.**call**     File
>   "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 227, in
>   lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result   ValueError: XPath
>   error: Invalid predicate in //a[@class = "next_page"/@href
>   2019-05-29 10:47:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider
>   (finished)   2019-05-29 10:47:16 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO:
>   Dumping Scrapy stats:   {'downloader/request_bytes': 621,
>   'downloader/request_count': 2,
>   'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
>   'downloader/response_bytes': 29812,    'downloader/response_count': 2,
>   'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,    'finish_reason':
>   'finished',    'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 29, 5, 47,
>   16, 767370),    'item_scraped_count': 1,    'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
>   'log_count/ERROR': 1,    'log_count/INFO': 9,
>   'response_received_count': 2,    'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
>   'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
>   'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,    'scheduler/dequeued': 1, 
>   'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,    'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
>   'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,    'spider_exceptions/ValueError': 1, 
>   'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 29, 5, 47, 14, 108786)}
>   2019-05-29 10:47:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed
>   (finished)

I am not sure that the problem is with xpath because in first attempt I get

> 'item_scraped_count': 30

but in here it is 1, which means spider isn't crawling even first page.

Comment: `next_page = response.selector.xpath('//a[@class = "next_page"/@href').extract()` here is your problem, missing `]`. xpath should be `'//a[@class = "next_page"]/@href`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix two issues to get your next page link working. Other than what @pako pointed out, you could have used `.extract_first()` or `.get()` to get the first item of an array. Rectified one should be more like `.xpath('//a[@class="next_page"]/@href').get()`. I've rewritten some of your xpaths to kick out whitespaces from the output.

```
class goodReadsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='goodreads'

    start_urls = ['https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?page=1']

    def parse(self,response):
        for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
            yield {
                'text':quote.xpath('normalize-space(.//div[@class="quoteText"]/text())').getall(),
                'author':quote.xpath('normalize-space(.//span[@class="authorOrTitle"]/text())').get(),
                'tags':quote.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"greyText")]/a/text()').getall()
            }

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="next_page"]/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            nlink = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=nlink,callback=self.parse)
```